# Is there a function in pandas like cumsum() but for the mean? I need to apply it based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I need to extract the cumulative mean only while my column A is different form zero. Each time it is zero, the cumulative mean should restart. Thanks so much in advance I am not so good using python.

Input:

```
    ColumnA
0   5
1   6
2   7
3   0
4   0
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   0
9   5
10  10
11  15
```

Expected Output:

```
    ColumnA CumulativeMean
0   5       5.0
1   6       5.5
2   7       6.0
3   0       0.0
4   0       0.0
5   1       1.0
6   2       1.5
7   3       2.0
8   0       0.0
9   5       5.0
10  10      7.5
11  15      10.0
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to implement this feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Off-site links are not acceptable.  Images of code and data are not acceptable.

Comment: The short answer to your question is `df["col"].expanding().mean()`

Comment: I improved the question (edited the input and expected output) as this is a good problem to solve that can be useful.

Comment: You need to do a `.groupby.` on two conditionals with `.shift()` and then use `.expanding().mean()`. I'll post a full answer if/when this can get opened. `df['CumulativeMean'] = (df.groupby((((df.shift()['ColumnA'] != 0) & (df['ColumnA'] == 0)) | (df.shift()['ColumnA'] == 0) & (df['ColumnA'] != 0)).cumsum())['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `cumsum` to make groups and then with `expanding`+`mean` to make the cumulative mean

```
groups=df.ColumnA.eq(0).cumsum()
df.groupby(groups).apply(lambda x: x[x.ne(0)].expanding().mean()).fillna(0)
```

---

**Details:**

Make groups when column is equal to 0 with `eq` and `cumsum`, since `eq` gives you a mask with True and False values, and with `cumsum` these values are taken as 1 or 0:

```
groups=df.ColumnA.eq(0).cumsum() 
groups
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
Name: ColumnA, dtype: int32
```

Then group by that groups and use apply to do the cumulative mean over elements different to 0:

```
df.groupby(groups).apply(lambda x: x[x.ne(0)].expanding().mean())
    ColumnA
0       5.0
1       5.5
2       6.0
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       1.0
6       1.5
7       2.0
8       NaN
9       5.0
10      7.5
11     10.0
```

And finally use fillna to fill with 0 the nan values:

```
df.groupby(groups).apply(lambda x: x[x.ne(0)].expanding().mean()).fillna(0)
    ColumnA
0       5.0
1       5.5
2       6.0
3       0.0
4       0.0
5       1.0
6       1.5
7       2.0
8       0.0
9       5.0
10      7.5
11     10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing to compare rows that are `==0` and `!=0` against the previous rows with `.shift()`. Then, jsut take the `.cumsum()` to separate into groups, according to where zeros are within `ColumnA`.

```
df['CumulativeMean'] = (df.groupby((((df.shift()['ColumnA'] != 0) & (df['ColumnA'] == 0)) |
                                     (df.shift()['ColumnA'] == 0) & (df['ColumnA'] != 0))
                          .cumsum())['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))


Out[6]: 
    ColumnA  CumulativeMean
0         5             5.0
1         6             5.5
2         7             6.0
3         0             0.0
4         0             0.0
5         1             1.0
6         2             1.5
7         3             2.0
8         0             0.0
9         5             5.0
10       10             7.5
11       15            10.0
```

I'll have broken down the logic of the `boolean indexing` within the `.groupby` statement down into multiple columns that build into the final result of the column `abcd_cumsum`. From there, `['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))` takes the mean of the group up to any given row in that group. For example, The second row (index of 1) takes the grouped mean of the first and second row, but excludes the third row.

```
df['a'] = (df.shift()['ColumnA'] != 0)
df['b'] = (df['ColumnA'] == 0)
df['ab'] = (df['a'] & df['b'])
df['c'] = (df.shift()['ColumnA'] == 0)
df['d'] = (df['ColumnA'] != 0)
df['cd'] = (df['c'] & df['d'])
df['abcd'] = (df['ab'] | df['cd'])
df['abcd_cumsum'] = (df['ab'] | df['cd']).cumsum()
df['CumulativeMean'] = (df.groupby(df['abcd_cumsum'])['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))

Out[7]: 
    ColumnA      a      b     ab      c      d     cd   abcd  abcd_cumsum  \
0         5   True  False  False  False   True  False  False            0   
1         6   True  False  False  False   True  False  False            0   
2         7   True  False  False  False   True  False  False            0   
3         0   True   True   True  False  False  False   True            1   
4         0  False   True  False   True  False  False  False            1   
5         1  False  False  False   True   True   True   True            2   
6         2   True  False  False  False   True  False  False            2   
7         3   True  False  False  False   True  False  False            2   
8         0   True   True   True  False  False  False   True            3   
9         5  False  False  False   True   True   True   True            4   
10       10   True  False  False  False   True  False  False            4   
11       15   True  False  False  False   True  False  False            4   

    CumulativeMean  
0              5.0  
1              5.5  
2              6.0  
3              0.0  
4              0.0  
5              1.0  
6              1.5  
7              2.0  
8              0.0  
9              5.0  
10             7.5  
11            10.0
```